# Python Selenium - How do I check if we have an item with this on HTML?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to check if we something with on the page as a trigger:

```
data-id="false_5511971198499@c.us_DBC6E6D07C76B179C26A40D689B2AEB2"
```

But, I need to check only `"data-id="false_"` because the rest could be anything.

I tried to create:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("[data-id='False']")
```

But didn't worked. And I don't know how to continue like if there is this element we need to `print(ok)`.

Could you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("[data-id='False']") this function is not working searching for: data-id="false_5511971198499@c.us_DBC6E6D07C76B179C26A40D689B2AEB2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dynamic element so you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@data-id, 'false_')]")))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-id^='false_']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//*[starts-with(@data_id,'false_')]
```